# Siegfried Bosch's Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra A Good Introduction?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, book-recommendation

**Since this post was flagged, I have edited the post so that it is less opinion based to fit the guidelines.**

So I have had quite a good amount of interest in Algebraic Geometry as of late and would like to ask about the following text:

[Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra by Siegfried Bosch Universitext)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1447148282)

I have mostly been exposed to Analysis (as noted with my posting history) so I would like a change of pace that isn't too sudden.
Another thing I would like is for the text to *not* to have a easily found Solutions Manual. I know I can get tempted if they exist for texts (I'm looking at you Baby Rudin).

*Quick Questions*: How is Bosch's book for a start? Is it a standard text for the subject / does it cover the standard topics needed? What are some pre-requisites for the text?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Bosch's book is good as an introduction. His treatment of commutative algebra is actually very good in my opinion. However I will warn you that it's not very geometric.